# Deleted Intellij sbt project keeps being recreated

Tags: scala, caching, intellij-idea, sbt, rm

A Scala project folder I am trying to delete keeps getting recreated / wont delete when I remove it.
I am using :
`rm -rf <folder>`
to remove a folder that I had pointed to in Intellij as a project.
I also tried:
`sudo rm -rf <folder>`
The following directory keeps getting recreated automatically:
`<folder>/project/target/config-classes`

What cache must I clear? Is this an sbt or Intellij issue? I am brand new to using both.

Answer (score 1):

Basically sbt does not need a configuration to run - if there are no files it assumes e.g. some `libraryDependencies`, `version`, etc.

If you run `sbt` command it will generate some files in order to stard building current directory (because to sbt *any* current directory is a build directory), so it will create e.g. project/target directory you see.

Another thing is *why* is sbt being run in the first place. I guess you have a project on list of recently opened projects in IntelliJ and it is on top, so when you start IntelliJ it tries to open all projects that were opened when you closed the app (basically restores the session). Since it cannot find the files it tries to regenerate the project and so it run sbt and you see what you see.

Try to *file* > *close project* to close your project *without* closing IntelliJ, so that it won't automatically open it again next time. Then you can remove it from the recently opened list and finally when you remove the directory it should not return.